# Faster alternative to execute a for loop on a data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame, df that has 10 million rows. I am running the below loop that takes a lot of time to execute. Can there be a faster way to do the same task?

```
for i in range(len(df)):
        if df['col_1'][i] in ('a','b', 'c', 'd', 'e'):
            df.at[i,'col_2']=1
        else:
            df.at[i,'col_2']=0
```

Comment: `df['col_2'] = df['col_1'].isin(['a','b','c','d','e']).astype(int)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [numpy.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to set values using boolean logic:

```
import numpy as np
df["col2"] = np.where(df["col1"].isin(('a','b', 'c', 'd', 'e')), 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use filtering based on loc-index. This code should do the trick:

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

df.loc[:, 'col2'] = 0
df.loc[df['col1'].isin(list1), 'col2'] = 1
```

So by default we first assign a zero to `col2`, then we assign a one, but only to those indexes, for which the `col1` value is in `list1`.